# Rolling restart with ansible handlers

Tags: ansible

I want to run an ansible playbook that installs a service and restarts it if anything has changed since the last run (more or less the canonical use-case for ansible handlers).

But I want a *different parallelism* for installing than for restarting: I want to install on all the hosts at a time but, if the "service-restart" handler gets invoked I want that to run on X hosts at a time.

I know this is possible with different plays that have different `serial` values. But I can't see how I could make use of handlers if I go this route. And I can't afford to have a single playbook with a `serial` value like `2`, as most of the time nothing will change for that service.

Can the handlers span multiple plays? Or is there any other way to do this without hacks?

Comment: It seems like you put `serial` into the handler restart task itself. Have you tried that?

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that `serial` can only be used at the play level. But it's definitely worth trying. I'll let you know.

Comment: If you'll take a look at `Rolling Updates` section in docs, you'll see they have examples of tasks with `serial` parameter in them...

Comment: Are you talking about this page http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html ? As far as I see, the `serial` attribute only occurs at the play level (and it's only documented to work that way). Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Mxx Sadly, I think this answers both your initial and follow-up suggestions: `ERROR: serial is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler`. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ansible 2.9.0 introduced the `throttle` keyword, which can be used at the task, block, or play level to limit the number of workers (up to the specified forks or serial setting) allowed.

For example, this can be used to restart nodes in a database cluster one by one:

```yaml
- name: Restart MySQL
  throttle: 1
  service:
    name: mysql
    state: restarted
```

Answer (score 6):

Handlers are just tasks that Ansible will run at the end of a play if necessary.  Given that they're implicitly added to the end of your play, they're going to be treated the same as any other tasks as far as parameters like `serial` go.  Unfortunately this means that without a feature request that the Ansible developers accept you're unlikely to see a change in the behavior of `serial` to support what you're trying to do.

I know you mentioned wanting to avoid hacks, but that's going to be the only way you can do something like this at this point.  It shouldn't be too difficult to set up something that's not a major hack, like creating a temporary file to flag the restart:

```
- hosts: some_hosts
  name: install service
  serial: 10
  - handlers:
      - name: schedule restart
        command: touch /tmp/restart_flag
  - tasks:
      - name: install service
        action: whatever...
        notify: schedule restart

- hosts: some_hosts
  name: restart service
  serial: 2
  - handlers:
    - name: perform restart
      service: name=foo state=restarted
  - tasks:
    - name: Delete /tmp/restart_flag. Restart service if file is deleted.
      file: path=/tmp/restart_flag state=absent
      notify: perform restart
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I found as well... The main problem is that I cannot make proper use of roles with this approach (I would like my roles to contain both tasks and handlers, with different parallelism).

Answer (score 3):

Currently it's not possible. There is an [issue oppened](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12170) for this.

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely the best place to move this conversation.